# C++ converting one integer to its word form

Tags: c++

**I am writing a C++ program to convert a number 1 - 9 to its word form. my piece of code is not working and i am getting the errors such as error:**

*case label ‘2’ not within a switch statement
problem6.cpp:21: error: break statement not within loop or switch*

How to fix this?

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 

int main() 
{ 
    char a = 0;



    cout << "enter amount of money: "; 
    cin >> a; 

    switch (a) 

    case 1 : 
        cout << "one "; 
        break; 

    case 2 : 
        cout << "two "; 
        break; 

    case 3 :
        cout << "three "; 
        break; 

    case 4 : 
        cout << "four "; 
        break; 

    case 5 : 
        cout << "five "; 
        break; 

    case 6 : 
        cout << "six ": 
        break; 

    case 7 : 
        cout << "seven "; 
        break; 

    case 8 : 
        cout << "eight "; 
        break; 

    case 9 : 
        cout << "nine "; 
        break; 


        return 0; 

}
```

Answer (score 5):

The reason for the error is that you didn't enclose the switch's *cases* within curly braces.

But I'm wondering why don't you define an array like this:

```
const char* numbers[] = {"zero", "one", "two", "three", .... etc};
```

And use it as:

```
 //must check the validity of the range!
 if ( a>=0 && a<=9 ) //or whatever the range you've defined. 
     cout << numbers[a];
```

Its also efficient, as **Acme** added in the comment.

Comment: Array is really efficient here.

Comment: @Acme: Yeah. Added that to my answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Acme: In fact it's equally efficient. for continuous rages switch is implemented using jump tables (your implementation) otherwise as if/else.

Comment: When i and Nawaz mentioned about `efficiency` we were talking about the simplistic and short nature of code, not the runtime efficiency.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the braces. Try

```
switch (a) 
{
case 1 : 
    cout << "one "; 
    break; 

case 2 : 
    cout << "two "; 
    break; 

case 3 :
    cout << "three "; 
    break; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your variable `a` to an `int`, or change all of your cases to their character equivalent (i.e., `1` to `'1'`, `2` to `'2'` etc).

Answer (score 0):

Fixed Code:

```
int a = 0; 

  switch (a) 

    { // Braces were missing
        case 1 : 
            cout << "one "; 
            break; 

        case 2 : 
            cout << "two "; 
            break; 

        case 3 :
            cout << "three "; 
            break; 

        case 4 : 
            cout << "four "; 
            break; 

        case 5 : 
            cout << "five "; 
            break; 

        case 6 : 
            cout << "six "; // You had a colon here instead of semi-colon
            break; 

        case 7 : 
            cout << "seven "; 
            break; 

        case 8 : 
            cout << "eight "; 
            break; 

        case 9 : 
            cout << "nine "; 
            break; 
    } // end of switch
```

I agree with Nawaz. Use array its much more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put all parts of the switch statement inside a pair of { }

```
switch(value)
{
case 1:
    Something();
    break;

case 2:
   Etc.

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work you had, amongst other things, missed a "}":

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 

int main() 
{ 
    char a = 0;     
    cout << "enter amount of money: "; 
    cin >> a; 

    int i = (int)a;
    switch (i) 
    {
       case 1 : 
          cout << "one "; 
          break; 
       case 2 : 
          cout << "two "; 
          break; 
       case 3 :
          cout << "three "; 
          break; 
       case 4 : 
          cout << "four "; 
          break; 
       case 5 : 
          cout << "five "; 
          break;
       case 6 : 
          cout << "six ": 
          break; 
       case 7 : 
          cout << "seven "; 
          break; 
       case 8 : 
         cout << "eight "; 
         break;
       case 9 : 
         cout << "nine "; 
         break;
    }

    return 0; 
 }
```

Comment: If the user enters '1', you're going to end up passing 49 into the switch.  You need to subtract '0' first (on systems using ASCII).